# Find asp:table from visual web part

Tags: 2013, web-part, visual-web-part

I've created a basic Visual Web Part, in VS 2017. When I Deploy it to my SharePoint server(2013) It works.

But I'm not sure how to find my table so I can add/remove values in the table.

My VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx :

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="vwp1.VisualWebPart1.VisualWebPart1UserControl" %>

<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server"></asp:Table>
```

My VisualWebPart.cs :

```
public class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart
{
    // Visual Studio might automatically update this path when you change the Visual Web Part project item.
    private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/15/vwp1/VisualWebPart1/VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx";

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
        Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to access Table1 from my `VisualWebPart1.cs` ?

Comment: The table is accesible from the user control itself. You really dont need to access it from VisualWebPart1 class. All logic should be located in VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs

Answer (score 0):

All `runat="server"` control are accessible in `.cs` file.

```
Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
Table tbl = (Table)this.FindControl("Table1");
// tbl....
Controls.Add(control);
```